# My admin control panel is hackable and I have no idea why

Tags: php

I have the following setup on my admin cpanel:

- /admincpanel/index.php
- /admincpanel/login.php
- /admincpanel/sendEmailsToAll.php

If a user is not logged in, it automatically goes back to login.php, so they can't access index.php and sendEmailsToAll.php without being logged in it.

On both pages I do the following:

```
    require "logincheck.php";
```

The logincheck looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logincheck'])) {
    echo '<script language="Javascript">';
    echo 'window.location="login.php"';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

So if I browse manually to any of those pages without being logged, it works and it brings me back to the login page.

I've tried to run a Audit Tool (Acunetix) on the website.

The tool was able to identify and do POST requests to both index and sendemails pages (so it actually sent email to my address with gibberish)  without authenticating first.

How could I prevent this?

Comment: Not everyone will run Javascript, the tool you used likely doesn't.  Use `header` to relocate with PHP, not Javascript.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Hint: What will happen after those lines run?

Comment: You should never rely on client side scripts (such as JavaScript) for security - they're all bypass-able. Instead, use server side, such as in @Jessica's answer

Comment: I've changed it to Jessica's code and suddenly the audit tool no longer finds index.php or SendEmailsToAll.php. Didn't know it would cause that much of an impact! Thanks everybody

Answer (score 17):

Don't use JAVASCRIPT to do a redirect! Use

```
header('Location: login.php'); 
exit;
```

Comment: Wow. I've changed it and instantly fixed the problem. They audit tool no longer finds the other 2 files. Thank you soo much! Can you explain me why it makes that of an impact? Thanks again!

Comment: Because javascript can be turned off by the user, and is typically off by default for tools (like a crawler). All anyone has to do to get into your admin is disable JS in their browser. That's VERY insecure. I suggest doing a ton of research on web security.

Comment: You may want to clear the output buffer before sending a header, if any HTML has already been sent.